# Park a domain using cPanel's UAPI

Tags: cpanel

What is the UAPI command to park a domain name in cPanel? I've been [going through the documentation](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/UAPI+Functions+-+DomainInfo%3A%3Alist_domains) though there does not seem to be much in regards to domain names. The other API methods are either deprecated or don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind that there are different levels of accounts (shared, reseller, VPS, and dedicated are the ones that I'm aware of) so I do *not* know which API requires which levels of access so check with with the cPanel forums or your web host.

That being said I did not care how I achieved this goal (since there are a few different APIs) only that I *did* achieve this goal in a way that can be automated by PHP.

1. It is critical to create the [xmlapi.php](https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php/blob/master/xmlapi.php) file.
2. Use the following code; change the `$user`, `$pass` and domain name:

---

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include('xmlapi.php');
$ip = '127.0.0.1';
$user = 'cpanel_user';
$pass = 'cpanel_pass';
$xmlapi = new xmlapi($ip);
$xmlapi->password_auth($user,$pass);
$xmlapi->api2_query($user,'Park','park',array('domain' => 'example.com'));
?>
```

If you have a reseller or higher account and have multiple users with access to their own copies of cPanel it is important to ensure that you login with the correct credentials. Do not use the root user because the root user is not the cPanel user which will host the parked domains.